# Pass argument through jquery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

`$(buttonID).on('click', onClickAddUpdate);`

which calls onClickAddUpdate when button id is pressed.  The thing is, can I pass a parameter into onClickAddUpdate? ie:

`$(buttonID).on('click', onClickAddUpdate(i));`

where `i` is the id of a `div` I want to access.

The remaining code is structured like this:

```
 var onClickAddUpdate;

 onClickAddUpdate = function(){

 /*add  paragraph element to div tag */
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can, in this way (take a look at [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)) :

```
var onClickAddUpdate = function(e) {
  console.log(e.data.i);
}

$(buttonID).on('click', {i: '1'}, onClickAddUpdate);
```

Test on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncuJB/).

Another way is:

```
var onClickAddUpdate = function(id) {
  console.log(id);
}

$(buttonID).on('click', function() {
    onClickAddUpdate(i);
});
```

Test on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zNmmu/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can,

see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Section *Passing data to the handler*

Example:

```
$(buttonID).on('click', {i: '1'}, onClickAddUpdate );
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do it:

```
var onClickAddUpdate = function(e, id) {
     console.log(id);
}

$(buttonID).on('click', function(e) { onClickAddUpdate(e, $(this).attr('id')) });
```